# Why isn't the draw method of the custom CALayer called earlier?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, timer, draw

**Issue**

I trigger random animations on a selection of UIViews using a Timer. All animations work as intended but one where the draw method of a CALayer is called after the exit of the timer selector.

**Detailed Description**

For the sake of clarity and simplification, let me schematise the actions performed.

[image: Cycle]

All the animations I have created so far work as intended: they are a combination of CABasicAnimations on existing subviews/sublayers or new ones added to the selected view hierarchy. They are coded as an UIView extension, so that they can be called on any views, irrespectively of the view or the view controller the view is in. Well, all work except one.

I have indeed created a custom CALayer class which consists in drawing patterns on a CALayer. In an extension of this custom class, there is a method to animate those patterns (see hereafter the code). So all in all, when I reach the step/method `animate selected view` and run this particular animation, here is what *should happen*:

- a method named animatePattern is called
- this method adds the custom CALayer class to the selected view and then calls the animation extension of this layer

**The issue**: if with all the other animations, all the drawings are performed prior to the exit of the `animate selected view` step/method, in that particular case, the custom CALayer class draw method is called **after** the exit of the `performAnimation` method, which in turn results in the crash of the animation.

I should add that I have tried the custom CALayer class animation in a separate and simplified playground and it works well (I add the custom layer to a `UIView` in the UIViewController's `viewDidLoad` method and then I call the layer animation in the UIViewController's `viewDidAppear` method.)

**The code**

- the method called by `animate selected view` step/method:

  ```
  func animatePattern(for duration: TimeInterval = 1) {

  let patternLayer        = PatternLayer(effectType: .dark)
  patternLayer.frame      = self.bounds
  self.layer.addSublayer(patternLayer)
  patternLayer.play(for: duration)

  }
  ```

(note that this method is in a UIView extension, therefore `self` here represents the UIView on which the animation has been called)

- the simplified custom CALayer Class:

  ```
  override var bounds: CGRect {
      didSet {
          self.setNeedsDisplay()
      }


  // Initializers
  override init() {
      super.init()
      self.setNeedsDisplay()
  }


  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }


  init(effectType: EffectType){
      super.init()
      // sets various properties
      self.setNeedsDisplay()
  }


  // Drawing
  override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
      super.draw(in: ctx)
      guard self.frame        != CGRect.zero else { return }

      self.masksToBounds      = true

      // do the drawings
  }
  ```
- the animation extension of the custom CALayer class:

  ```
   func play(for duration: Double, removeAfterCompletion: RemoveAfterCompletion = .no) {

      guard self.bounds != CGRect.zero else {
          print("Cannot animate nil layer")
          return }

      CATransaction.begin()

      CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {

          if removeAfterCompletion.removeStatus {
              if case RemoveAfterCompletion.yes = removeAfterCompletion { self.fadeOutDuration = 0.0 }
              self.fadeToDisappear(duration: &self.fadeOutDuration)
          }
      }


      // perform animations

      CATransaction.commit()
  }
  ```

**Attempts so far**

I have tried to force draw the layer by inserting `setNeedsDisplay` / `setNeedsLayout` at various places in the code but it does not work: debugging the custom CALayer class's `draw` method is constantly reached after the exit of the `performAnimation` method, whilst it should be called when the layer's frame is modified in the `animatePattern` method. I must miss something quite obvious but I am currently running in circles and I'd appreciate a fresh pair of eyes on it.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to consider this issue!
Best,

Comment: For the draw layer can you give an example of the animations you are performing where you have //perform animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is frequently the case, when you take the time to write down your issue, new ideas start to pop up. In fact, I remembered that `self.setNeedsDisplay()` informs the system that the layer needs to be (re)drawn but it does not (re)draw it at once: it will be done during the next refresh. It seems then that the refresh occurs after the end of the cycle for that specific animation. In order to overcome this is issue, I first added a call for the `display` method right after the patternLayer bounds are set, and it worked, but given @Matt comment, I changed the solution by calling `displayIfNeeded` method instead. It works as well.

```
func animatePattern(for duration: TimeInterval = 1) {

let patternLayer        = PatternLayer(effectType: .dark)
patternLayer.frame      = self.bounds
self.layer.addSublayer(patternLayer)

// asks the system to draw the layer now
patternLayer.displayIfNeeded()

patternLayer.play(for: duration)

}
```

Again, should anyone come up with another more elegant solution/explanation, please do not refrain to share!

Comment: First sentence in the docs for `display`: “Do not call this method directly.”

Comment: I am not calling CALayer’s display method, but the subclass’ display method.  But I’d like to hear your idea to overcome the issue otherwise :)

Comment: I didn't read your question deeply, but if I'm understanding correctly, the way I deal with this sort of thing is by introducing a short delay to allow the runloop to complete.

Comment: I just introduce a very brief `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` into the sequence of events.

Answer (score 0):

You override the draw(_ context) as the UIView can be the delegate of CALayer.

```
 UIView: {

    var patternLayer :  PatternLayer

     func animatePattern(for duration: TimeInterval = 1) {

      patternLayer      = PatternLayer(effectType: .dark)
       patternLayer.frame      = self.bounds
       self.layer.addSublayer(patternLayer)
     }

      func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext){
        layer.draw(ctx)
         if  NECESSARY { patternLayer.play(for: duration)}

        }

      }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to suggest a solution! As far as I understand your idea, I override `draw(_context:)` in the view that is subject to the animation. If so, that solution cannot work because the animation applies to a random selection of views, not one in particular. Whenever the timer reaches a certain time, it triggers some animations on some views, on of which is the one `patternLayer`.

Comment: That's NECESSARY coming from. The idea is to garantee calling animation after layer drawing with some conditions. displayIfNeeded() is good here too.

Comment: Thanks again :) but I might not fully understand your idea... Do you suggest to add this method in an UIView extension? In addition, this animation might not be the one selected to be run in the first place (there is a random selection of a view and an animation to be applied).

Comment: No. I mean your answer `patternLayer.displayIfNeeded()` is right here.